# can I get my service token from AZURE with just the client_secret using angular?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, adal

I want to consume a service but for this, I need to generate the token to later be able to access the API. This is possible using angular? This service has integrated azure. they only gave me the following data.

App Id or clientId::

Key Secret:

Tenant Id:

scope:

I have been looking for similar implementations and I cannot find with angular they all user authentication, and I do not have that data. I have searched for methods with `MSAL` or `ADAL` but I cannot find one with my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The scopes that you can get are identified in the app registration api permissions as "application permissions" and NOT "delegated permissions" client credentials flow cannot get delegated permissions flow. Also once you give an application permission, you have to click grant for tenant. If you don't it won't be able to use it. I assume you have an app registration for the API Service, and another app registration for the web app.

In the app registration for the service, you will have to add an app role in the manifest. This will make an application permission appear when you try to add an api permission from web app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes#scopes-to-request-access-to-all-the-permissions-of-a-v10-application

[image]

[image]